# Ubuntu read only file system on install?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

We've been trying to install the newest version of Ubuntu on an older HP DL320 G2 server, and for some reason it always puts the drives in readonly mode.  We can't edit or create anything, as our main user account or sudo'ing to root.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Show us the output of /etc/fstab, mount and /proc/mount.

Comment: I'll see what we can do ... at the moment we can't ssh into the box (can't configure ssh) and can't save to USB, which means I'd have to retype the output or just take a photo.

Comment: Even so ... would it be typical that the Ubuntu install would set the drive as ro in /etc/fstab, requiring a remount to do anything?  Just curious ... my sys admin has reinstalled it 3 times with the same results.

Comment: I'm not an ubuntu guy, Im a redhat guy, but I don't think that ubutnu would do that under normal circumstances, cat't see a reason to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up downloading a newer version of Ubuntu and installed without any problems.  For whatever reason the version of Fiesty Fawn we had just kept croaking.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't upgrade because it's read-only then start by looking at dmesg do see what that says. It'll probably be the system BIOS or the RAID controller BIOS thats marking it read only.

If it's installed, but you cannot write to the disk after booting, then check if the filesystems are mounted as readonly with the command "mount".

If it's readonly then you may need to run a fsck on the filesystem, or maybe just remount it rw.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when using disks that Linux for some reason think is faulty.
Did you reformat the entire disk when installing?